# Closable div - Left div slides close, while right div width expands

Tags: javascript, css, html

I'm trying to make a div on the left side that can close by sliding to the left While the content in the right div expands to 100% filling the space of the closed div. [image example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/76HQe.png)

I found a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/VLNDL/) here but its only for the closable div.

```
<div id="intro-wrap">
    <div class="open-intro">+</div>
    <div class="close-intro">-</div>

    <div id="contentWrap">
        <h1 class="main-header">Here is a Title</h1>
        <p class="main-desc">You can write whatever you want about yourself here. You can say you're a superhuman alien ant, arrived from the nether regions of Dwarf-Ant-Dom.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you open to jQuery solutions as this can be done rather simply/quickly?

Comment: Sure im open to any solutions at this point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has some work to do, but it'll get you started.

```js
$(function() {
  "use strict";

  var isOpen = true;

  $('#open-close').on('click', function() {
    if (isOpen) {
      animate(false);
      isOpen = false;
    } else {
      animate(true);
      isOpen = true;
    }
  });


});

function animate(action) {

  if (action) {
    $('#left').animate({ width: "30vw" }, 600);
    $('#right').animate({width: "70vw",marginLeft: "-5px"}, 600);
  } else {
    $('#left').animate({width: "0px"}, 600);
    $('#right').animate({width: "99vw" }, 600);
  }

}
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#wrapper{
width: 100vw;
height: 100px;  
border: 2px solid purple;  
}
#wrapper > *{
  display: inline-block;
}
#left {
  position: relative;
  width: 30vw;
  height: 100px;
  background: green;
}
#right {
  position: relative;
  width: 65vw;
  height: 100px;
  background: navy;
}
#open-close {
  position: absolute;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  background: red;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="wrapper">

  <div id="left"></div>

  <div id="right">
    <div id="open-close"></div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Sweet this is exactly what I was trying to do

Comment: Glad to help, don't forget to check the answer as correct :)

Comment: Its animating in the `code snipet`, do some tests on your own, perform debugging, if nothing works after a while, then and only then you should post another question.

Your question wast  more a give me the code "question", and here we normally help after you have provided your own work and ran into trouble, I helped you this first time so you wouldn't get more downvotes and started learning more about  StackOverflow.

Check your code, you know that the answer works so you must be doing something wrong.